# How to know when to pray?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

Nearly every single mosque or prayer time table web site has different timings, that differ between each other in hours, therefore **how would I know whether I am praying too early or not?**

Due to the nature of the whether and buildings surrounding me, I am not able to get a clear view of the sun or see the sun at most times.

I wonder if this disagreement with prayer times calculations is derived from our over complication of the matter, as in the time of the Prophet PBUH they did not have the technologies to calculate which degree the sun is at etc.....

Comment: you simply find the city that is closest to you and follow that. Did you try: http://www.salahtimes.com/ ?

Comment: I think I covered your Question here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32643/figuring-out-right-calculation-method-of-prayer-time

Comment: @Ahmedilyas, Like I said each mosque has its own prayer times different from any any other. So prayer times are not a default for each city, unlike in Arab countries where the call to prayer is synchronised

Comment: Actually because some school of thoughts differ in the timing of the salah, but that difference is not like very big difference, there are slight things which differ, mostly on time of asar. Otherwise start and end time of prayers are mostly same. And we can easily find a time in which all parties agree that salah is valid and it is valid time of the salah, like some sort of intersection of all views. You can follow any particular view, which you may prefer on others. Or you can look for intersection timing.

Answer (score -1):

I think covered your Question here so please check it [London Prayer Times](https://packagespoint.com/london-prayer-times-prayer-times-london-html/)