# Adhan and timings of prayer

Tags: prayer-timings, adhan

I live in a place where i could barely listen to the adhan. So, i chose an alternative app for my prayer timings. I completely follow my mobile adhan like mosque. Also, I have verified the timing as both mosque and my mobile adhan ring at same time at magrib. As we know for magrib there should be accuracy in timing. So, on the basis of this,"i consider it's timing to be perfect".

Do i have to silent my app adhan when I'm able listen mosque adhan ?

Do i have to wait for the mosque adhan for my prayer if at zhuhr my app rings first ?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE. Note that adhan times for maghrib (at least for sunnis) and dhor are certainly the same for any calculation methode. The 'asr time may very as there's a difference between the hanafis and the rest of the sunni madhhabs. Issues with calculation methods will only arise with 'Isha' and possibly fajr time. Some considering your method as perfect based on maghrib time is wrong details are explained in [figuring out right calculation method for prayer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32643/figuring-out-right-calculation-method-of-prayer-time)

Comment: I never knew that. Thanks to allah i came to know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to listen or hear the adhan you should follow it. Calculation methods have some inaccuracies (and the more you are far away from the "reference location" of the calculation the more inaccurate they are) and saddly most of the app's that you may find don't add the necessary information about which calculcation method is more recommended (correct) to use in your area.

Such apps may have a couple of uses, but they are in first place intended for the use in non-Muslim countries where people may not hear the adhan at all and the majority of the people don't have any knowledge on how to find  out the correct prayer timings, while in Muslim countries these timings are not only calculation, but also experience based. As earlier Muslims knew much better than us when the prayer time starts or ends.

The adhan that counts for you is the one you hear by a real human voice if you are in a Muslim country.